# Kubuntu/Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa LTS freezing randomly

Tags: kubuntu, freeze, radeon

I am newbie in Ubuntu world who have just recently started to use after migrating from window. I have been experiencing very weird random frequent freeze in Ubuntu/Kubuntu. I am using 16GB of memory and 8GB of SWAP. I suspect that either my RAM or Graphics memory is the culprit. I never had this issue in window. I tested memory issue with memtest, and result was OK. There was no issue.

```
My Graphics card information is this 

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: X.Org (0x1002)
    Device: AMD CAICOS (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-42-generic, LLVM 10.0.0) (0x6779)
    Version: 20.0.8
    Accelerated: yes
    Video memory: 2048MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.1
Memory info (GL_ATI_meminfo):
    VBO free memory - total: 2047 MB, largest block: 2047 MB
    VBO free aux. memory - total: 1021 MB, largest block: 1021 MB
    Texture free memory - total: 2047 MB, largest block: 2047 MB
    Texture free aux. memory - total: 1021 MB, largest block: 1021 MB
    Renderbuffer free memory - total: 2047 MB, largest block: 2047 MB
    Renderbuffer free aux. memory - total: 1021 MB, largest block: 1021 MB
Memory info (GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info):
    Dedicated video memory: 2048 MB
    Total available memory: 3069 MB
    Currently available dedicated video memory: 2047 MB
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD CAICOS (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-42-generic, LLVM 10.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 20.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
```

I also tried using `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` resources just to check if this was fault with not having a proprietary driver, but still I had a random freeze.

I have been experiencing this frequent freeze mostly when system resumes from sleep. After 2-5 times consecutive waking up after sleep mode, it starts to freeze and throws error like this. This is the crash log from latest freeze.

```
Jul 30 22:57:46 user-System kernel: [53089.863335] [TTM] Erroneous page count. Leaking pages.
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960183] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000000
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960188] #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960189] #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960191] PGD 8000000414729067 P4D 8000000414729067 PUD 0 
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960195] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960198] CPU: 0 PID: 147 Comm: kswapd0 Not tainted 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960200] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P8H77-V LE, BIOS 1307 03/17/2014
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960207] RIP: 0010:__cpa_process_fault+0xf1/0x640
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960209] Code: 1c b8 00 00 00 80 41 bc f2 ff ff ff 48 8d 84 01 00 00 a0 a5 48 c1 e8 0c 48 39 c2 73 a3 48 8b 03 4c 89 fe 48 c7 c7 d0 94 d5 a6 <48> 8b 10 e8 42 e9 01 00 0f 0b 41 bc f2 ff ff ff eb 84 48 89 f2 4c
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960211] RSP: 0000:ffffb7e7c01c78e0 EFLAGS: 00010283
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960212] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffb7e7c01c7ab0 RCX: 000000023a800000
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960214] RDX: 00000000001847e6 RSI: fff0ea1e9e1d1000 RDI: ffffffffa6d594d0
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960215] RBP: ffffb7e7c01c7948 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00000000001847e6
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960217] R10: 00000001847e6000 R11: ffffffffffffffff R12: 00000000fffffff2
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960219] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffb7e7c01c7ab0 R15: fff0ea1e9e1d1000
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960221] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffa0209f800000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960222] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960224] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 00000002c16e2004 CR4: 00000000000606f0
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960225] Call Trace:
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960230]  __change_page_attr+0x62c/0x730
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960234]  ? smp_call_function_many+0x1e0/0x270
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960236]  __change_page_attr_set_clr+0x66/0x290
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960239]  change_page_attr_set_clr+0x14d/0x200
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960242]  set_pages_array_wb+0x2b/0x80
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960249]  ttm_pages_put+0x74/0x80 [ttm]
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960254]  ttm_page_pool_free+0x159/0x1b0 [ttm]
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960259]  ttm_pool_shrink_scan+0xce/0x110 [ttm]
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960263]  do_shrink_slab+0x150/0x2a0
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960265]  shrink_slab+0xac/0x2a0
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960267]  shrink_node+0xd3/0x400
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960269]  balance_pgdat+0x319/0x590
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960271]  kswapd+0x1ff/0x3c0
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960274]  ? wait_woken+0x80/0x80
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960277]  kthread+0x104/0x140
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960278]  ? balance_pgdat+0x590/0x590
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960280]  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960283]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960285] Modules linked in: xt_MASQUERADE nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_nat rfcomm overlay aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_usb_audio snd_usbmidi_lib kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm gspca_sonixj gspca_main videobuf2_vmalloc btusb videobuf2_memops btrtl snd_seq_midi videobuf2_v4l2 snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_common iwlmvm btbcm videodev btintel mac80211 mc eeepc_wmi snd_rawmidi asus_wmi bluetooth wmi_bmof sparse_keymap libarc4 joydev input_leds snd_seq ecdh_generic snd_seq_device ecc iwlwifi snd_timer cfg80211 snd mei_me soundcore mei mac_hid nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG xt_limit xt_addrtype xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960318]  nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c sch_fq_codel br_netfilter ip6table_filter ip6_tables bridge stp llc iptable_filter arp_tables parport_pc bpfilter ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul i915 radeon ghash_clmulni_intel ttm i2c_algo_bit uas drm_kms_helper syscopyarea cryptd usb_storage i2c_i801 lpc_ich sysfillrect r8169 sysimgblt fb_sys_fops pata_acpi realtek drm wmi video
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960340] CR2: 0000000000000000
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960342] ---[ end trace 0320813814827cec ]---
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960345] RIP: 0010:__cpa_process_fault+0xf1/0x640
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960347] Code: 1c b8 00 00 00 80 41 bc f2 ff ff ff 48 8d 84 01 00 00 a0 a5 48 c1 e8 0c 48 39 c2 73 a3 48 8b 03 4c 89 fe 48 c7 c7 d0 94 d5 a6 <48> 8b 10 e8 42 e9 01 00 0f 0b 41 bc f2 ff ff ff eb 84 48 89 f2 4c
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960349] RSP: 0000:ffffb7e7c01c78e0 EFLAGS: 00010283
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960350] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffb7e7c01c7ab0 RCX: 000000023a800000
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960351] RDX: 00000000001847e6 RSI: fff0ea1e9e1d1000 RDI: ffffffffa6d594d0
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960352] RBP: ffffb7e7c01c7948 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00000000001847e6
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960354] R10: 00000001847e6000 R11: ffffffffffffffff R12: 00000000fffffff2
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960355] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffb7e7c01c7ab0 R15: fff0ea1e9e1d1000
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960356] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffffa0209f800000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960358] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 30 22:57:50 user-System kernel: [53093.960359] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 00000002c16e2004 CR4: 00000000000606f0
```

This is previous freeze crash log from kernel:

```
  Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323658] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 22s! [dolphin:147382]
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323661] Modules linked in: nf_conntrack_netlink usblp xt_nat veth xt_MASQUERADE nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_nat rfcomm overlay aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec intel_rapl_common snd_hda_core snd_usbmidi_lib x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hwdep coretemp snd_pcm kvm snd_seq_midi eeepc_wmi gspca_sonixj snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm intel_cstate gspca_main asus_wmi intel_rapl_perf btusb mac80211 wmi_bmof snd_rawmidi sparse_keymap videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl snd_seq libarc4 videobuf2_common btbcm btintel videodev joydev input_leds mc snd_seq_device bluetooth iwlwifi snd_timer cfg80211 snd ecdh_generic ecc mei_me soundcore mei mac_hid nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG xt_limit
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323686]  xt_addrtype sch_fq_codel xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c ip6table_filter br_netfilter ip6_tables bridge iptable_filter stp llc arp_tables parport_pc bpfilter ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid i915 radeon crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ttm ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper uas syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops usb_storage lpc_ich pata_acpi i2c_i801 r8169 drm realtek wmi video
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323705] CPU: 2 PID: 147382 Comm: dolphin Tainted: G      D           5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323706] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P8H77-V LE, BIOS 1307 03/17/2014
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323710] RIP: 0010:native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath+0x60/0x1d0
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323712] Code: 6e f0 0f ba 2f 08 0f 92 c0 0f b6 c0 c1 e0 08 89 c2 8b 07 30 e4 09 d0 a9 00 01 ff ff 75 48 85 c0 74 0e 8b 07 84 c0 74 08 f3 90 <8b> 07 84 c0 75 f8 b8 01 00 00 00 5d 66 89 07 c3 8b 37 81 fe 00 01
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323713] RSP: 0018:ffffa7664b67bb78 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323715] RAX: 0000000000000101 RBX: ffffa7664b67bc60 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323716] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffffff8d37e608
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323717] RBP: ffffa7664b67bb78 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffffffff8ba77600
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323718] R10: ffffa7664b67bcf0 R11: 0000000000000002 R12: 0000000000000001
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323718] R13: ffffffff8d37e608 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: 0000000000000001
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323720] FS:  00007f0f2438f4c0(0000) GS:ffff969b9f900000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323721] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323722] CR2: 00007f0f2202a310 CR3: 00000001f16b4001 CR4: 00000000000606e0
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323723] Call Trace:
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323727]  _raw_spin_lock+0x1e/0x30
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323729]  __change_page_attr_set_clr+0x5b/0x290
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323732]  ? _vm_unmap_aliases+0x117/0x130
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323733]  change_page_attr_set_clr+0x14d/0x200
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323736]  set_memory_ro+0x29/0x30
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323739]  bpf_int_jit_compile+0x2cc/0x333
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323741]  bpf_prog_select_runtime+0xa7/0x130
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323744]  bpf_prepare_filter+0x44c/0x4b0
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323745]  __get_filter+0xba/0x110
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323747]  sk_attach_filter+0x19/0x60
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323749]  ? _copy_from_user+0x3e/0x60
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323750]  sock_setsockopt+0x949/0xce0
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323753]  __sys_setsockopt+0x160/0x180
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323755]  __x64_sys_setsockopt+0x25/0x30
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323757]  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323759]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323761] RIP: 0033:0x7f0f2754d71e
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323762] Code: d8 64 89 02 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff eb bb 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 49 89 ca b8 36 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 42 77 0c 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323763] RSP: 002b:00007fff74266018 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000036
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323765] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fff74266080 RCX: 00007f0f2754d71e
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323765] RDX: 000000000000001a RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 0000000000000010
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323766] RBP: 000000000000001b R08: 0000000000000010 R09: 00000000ffffffff
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323767] R10: 00007fff74266070 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000000000000001d
Jul 24 21:02:47 user-System kernel: [64867.323768] R13: 00007fff74266050 R14: 00007fff74266160 R15: 00007fff74266158

Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716427] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716431] NETDEV WATCHDOG: enp3s0 (r8169): transmit queue 0 timed out
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716445] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 0 at net/sched/sch_generic.c:447 dev_watchdog+0x258/0x260
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716446] Modules linked in: nf_conntrack_netlink usblp xt_nat veth xt_MASQUERADE nfnetlink xfrm_user xfrm_algo iptable_nat nf_nat rfcomm overlay aufs cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_usb_audio snd_hda_codec intel_rapl_common snd_hda_core snd_usbmidi_lib x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hwdep coretemp snd_pcm kvm snd_seq_midi eeepc_wmi gspca_sonixj snd_seq_midi_event iwlmvm intel_cstate gspca_main asus_wmi intel_rapl_perf btusb mac80211 wmi_bmof snd_rawmidi sparse_keymap videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 btrtl snd_seq libarc4 videobuf2_common btbcm btintel videodev joydev input_leds mc snd_seq_device bluetooth iwlwifi snd_timer cfg80211 snd ecdh_generic ecc mei_me soundcore mei mac_hid nf_log_ipv6 ip6t_REJECT nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_log_ipv4 nf_log_common ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_LOG xt_limit
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716471]  xt_addrtype sch_fq_codel xt_tcpudp xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c ip6table_filter br_netfilter ip6_tables bridge iptable_filter stp llc arp_tables parport_pc bpfilter ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid i915 radeon crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ttm ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper uas syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops usb_storage lpc_ich pata_acpi i2c_i801 r8169 drm realtek wmi video
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716490] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Tainted: G      D      L    5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716491] Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/P8H77-V LE, BIOS 1307 03/17/2014
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716492] RIP: 0010:dev_watchdog+0x258/0x260
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716494] Code: 85 c0 75 e5 eb 9f 4c 89 ff c6 05 1f f5 e7 00 01 e8 8d bb fa ff 44 89 e9 4c 89 fe 48 c7 c7 e8 7d c3 8c 48 89 c2 e8 83 2f 71 ff <0f> 0b eb 80 0f 1f 40 00 66 66 66 66 90 55 48 89 e5 41 57 49 89 d7
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716495] RSP: 0018:ffffa766400d8e30 EFLAGS: 00010286
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716496] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff969b9c280600 RCX: 0000000000000006
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716497] RDX: 0000000000000007 RSI: 0000000000000096 RDI: ffff969b9f8978c0
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716498] RBP: ffffa766400d8e60 R08: 000000000000fcfe R09: ffffffff8d3aef7c
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716499] R10: ffffffff8d3941a8 R11: ffffa766400d8c98 R12: 0000000000000001
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716500] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffff969b9d2b2480 R15: ffff969b9d2b2000
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716501] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff969b9f880000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716502] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716503] CR2: 00007f75ddd844f8 CR3: 0000000179e0a006 CR4: 00000000000606e0
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716504] Call Trace:
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716506]  <IRQ>
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716509]  ? pfifo_fast_enqueue+0x150/0x150
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716512]  call_timer_fn+0x32/0x130
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716514]  __run_timers.part.0+0x180/0x280
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716515]  ? enqueue_hrtimer+0x3d/0x90
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716518]  ? recalibrate_cpu_khz+0x10/0x10
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716520]  ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716522]  run_timer_softirq+0x2a/0x50
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716524]  __do_softirq+0xe1/0x2d6
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716525]  ? hrtimer_interrupt+0x13b/0x220
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716527]  irq_exit+0xae/0xb0
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716529]  smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x7b/0x140
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716531]  apic_timer_interrupt+0xf/0x20
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716532]  </IRQ>
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716534] RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xc2/0x450
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716536] Code: 66 90 31 ff e8 bf 08 81 ff 80 7d c7 00 74 17 9c 58 66 66 90 66 90 f6 c4 02 0f 85 65 03 00 00 31 ff e8 12 6c 87 ff fb 66 66 90 <66> 66 90 45 85 ed 0f 88 8f 02 00 00 49 63 cd 4c 8b 7d d0 4c 2b 7d
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716537] RSP: 0018:ffffa7664008be38 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716538] RAX: ffff969b9f8aad00 RBX: ffffffff8cf59c00 RCX: 000000000000001f
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716539] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000026c9b3f7 RDI: 0000000000000000
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716540] RBP: ffffa7664008be78 R08: 00003aff6ccc9df3 R09: 0000000000000001
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716541] R10: ffff969b9f8a9a00 R11: ffff969b9f8a99e0 R12: ffff969b9f8b5300
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716542] R13: 0000000000000004 R14: 0000000000000004 R15: ffff969b9f8b5300
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716544]  ? cpuidle_enter_state+0xa1/0x450
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716545]  cpuidle_enter+0x2e/0x40
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716547]  call_cpuidle+0x23/0x40
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716548]  do_idle+0x1dd/0x270
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716550]  cpu_startup_entry+0x20/0x30
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716552]  start_secondary+0x167/0x1c0
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716554]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Jul 24 21:02:48 user-System kernel: [64868.716556] ---[ end trace 4fdb3e94db13f1e8 ]---

Jul 24 21:02:50 user-System kernel: [64870.981570] GpuWatchdog[2662]: segfault at 0 ip 000055ca74a5f52c sp 00007f049386b310 error 6 in brave[55ca6f932000+8397000]
Jul 24 21:02:50 user-System kernel: [64870.981579] Code: 89 de e8 f7 a1 0a ff 80 7d c7 00 79 09 48 8b 7d b0 e8 08 24 64 fe 41 8b 84 24 e0 00 00 00 89 45 b0 48 8d 7d b0 e8 94 3c 5a fb <c7> 04 25 00 00 00 00 37 13 00 00 48 83 c4 48 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e
```

lshw -C memory

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1307
       date: 03/17/2014
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 128KiB
       capabilities: internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: internal varies unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2 DISABLED
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: internal unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System memory
       physical id: 1
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: HMT351U6CFR8C-PB
          vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
          physical id: 0
          serial: 1E8E8310
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: HMT351U6CFR8C-PB
          vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
          physical id: 1
          serial: 1E5E832A
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: HMT351U6CFR8C-PB
          vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
          physical id: 2
          serial: 1E3E8327
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: HMT351U6CFR8C-PB
          vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
          physical id: 3
          serial: 1E6E8312
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
```

○ → free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       6.4Gi       797Mi       541Mi       8.3Gi       8.2Gi
Swap:         8.0Gi       9.0Mi       8.0Gi
```

○ → sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 25
```

○ → grep -i swap /etc/fstab

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Does these problem and error logs mean that Linux is having a hard time to manage memory mapping or clear used RAM memory after resume Or Am I having some kind of memory leak?
I would be very thankful if someone could point me in the right direction to resolve this issue.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What exact processor? What exact memory? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Is your CPU or RAM overclocked? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema, Thanks for your comment. I have updated my question with those requested parameter. Would be thankful if you have more insights on this.

Comment: Your `L3 Cache` is disabled. Have you done any tweaks that might have caused that? When you ran `memtest`, did you run all 4/4 test passes?

Comment: @heynnema, No i haven't done any tweaks for disabling L3 cache. I am also not exactly sure why it is disabled. During startup logs, I could see some entries where it mention as `MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.`, and unfortunately there is also no further BIOS updates available. Could it be because of Meltdown/Spectre CPU bug and to fix that it has been disabled by Kernel or something?

Comment: @heynnema, 
Yes, I also ran 4/4 memtest and it passed without any errors.

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, re-run the `sudo lshw -C memory` command, and see if `L3 Cache` shows as disabled. If it does, you may have a motherboard problem... and that might explain your other question about MTTR. I'll post an answer about the MDS bug.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Your BIOS is current at version 1307.

**L3 Cache**

re: *I suspect that either my RAM or Graphics memory is the culprit.*

`sudo lshw -C memory` shows that L3 Cache is disabled. That isn't right. You may have a motherboard hardware problem.

```
 *-cache:2 DISABLED
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       capabilities: internal unified
       configuration: level=3
```

Try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, do `sudo lshw -C memory`, and note if you see the same thing.

**MDS bug**

```
MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html 
for more details.
```

**Mitigation control on the kernel command line**

The kernel command line allows to control the MDS mitigations at boot time with the option “mds=”. The valid arguments for this option are:

```
full
```

If the CPU is vulnerable, enable all available mitigations for the MDS vulnerability, CPU buffer clearing on exit to userspace and when entering a VM. Idle transitions are protected as well if SMT is enabled.

It does not automatically disable SMT.

```
full,nosmt
```

The same as mds=full, with SMT disabled on vulnerable CPUs. This is the complete mitigation.

```
off
```

Disables MDS mitigations completely.

---

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

To:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mds=full,nosmt"
```

Save the file and quit `gedit`.

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`

**Note: Understand that you'll take a HUGE performance hit on multi-cpu or multi-core configurations.**

**Note: If the performance hit is too great, try `mds=full` instead of `mds=full,nosmt`.**

Comment: Thank you for your comment once again. 
RE: _shows that L3 Cache is disabled. That isn't right. You may have a motherboard hardware problem._
- At least, I can confirm that it was working fine under windows 10 and I am also being surprised to see this just in Ubuntu.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mds=full,nosmt"`
was this the solution for handling CPU bug, or this is the solution for original issue for having a random freeze?

Comment: @hsinam Windows working or not working has nothing to do with Ubuntu working or not working. Windows also doesn't show you the L1/2/3 caches like Ubuntu does. You should be booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to check on the L3 Cache. The MDS patch for for handling the MDS error message that you asked about. Please see my earlier comment, above.

Comment: I added those line with `mds=full,nosmt` and it ruined my whole day. Machine was so slow that it took almost couple of hours to just show the boot screen. Had a hard time in removing the nosmt and add only `mds=full` in the grub changes.
However, upon checking kernel log there was still those `MDS CPU bug present..` info text
In the documentation, it also states as `Not specifying this option is equivalent to “mds=full”....`, Did I understand correctly that since adding nosmt gives a huge performance hit, now adding just mds=full or leaving without it, doesn't matter?

Comment: @hsinam `mds=full` is not as much a performance hit as `mds=full,nosmt`. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html  for more info. Did you boot to a Ubuntu Live to see if L3 cache is enabled?

Comment: Yes, i boot into Ubuntu live and checked for L3 cache. It was also stated as disabled there as well. I also didn't see any option in BIOS for enabling or disabling anything cache specific, but at least I could see L3 cache being correctly recognized in BIOS.. Upon quick googling I found fewer other people also had similar issues with L3 cache

with respect to "mds=full" as per your linked documentation it states that `Not specifying this option is equivalent to “mds=full”....,` so did I understand correctly that now adding just mds=full or leaving without it, doesn't matter?

Comment: @hsinam The point of booting to a Ubuntu Live, and checking the L3 Cache, was to eliminate a software problem on your regular Ubuntu installation. The fact that it still showed as disabled, suggests to me that you've either got a hardware problem, or, if there's a way in Windows to confirm L3 Cache operation, then a Ubuntu problem. The mds docs are a little confusing... "full" is partial mitigation, "full,nosmt" is complete mitigation, and "off" is nothing. If your kernel is up to date, the mds thing is probably taken care of, without the mds= thingie.

Comment: I seriously couldn't find a way to enable L3 cache. Upon googling I even saw other more people with similar issues, therefore I am not entirely convinced that this could be a hardware error. In any case would you happen to have any suggestion on what to do in this matter?

Also, Does this have anything to do with frequent freezing as freezing mostly happens while waking up from sleep only. If I regularly shutdown and start normally, everything works normally. Would you happen to have any suggestion to this issue as well?

Comment: @hsinam No, I don't think that there's anything you can do about enabling the L3 Cache. I'd contact the manufacturer's support folks and ask them. I still think it's a hardware error.